# How to print binary string of certain position

Tags: string, matlab, binary

consider

```
a = dec2bin(rand(5,1)*100);
X = 3:7;
Z = 2:6;
for i = 1:5
    y    =  abs(X(i)-Z);
    dm   = min(y);
    D(i) = find(y==min(y));
end
D2 = D'
b  = a(D')
```

Output is

```
a =
01001
01110
10000
10011
11111

X =
 3     4     5     6     7

Z =
 2     3     4     5     6

D2 =
 2
 3
 4
 5
 5

b =
0
1
1
1
1
```

why it did not return

```
b = [01110
     10000
     10011
     11111]
```

How will i get this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
b=dec2bin(a(D'))
```

That gives me:

```
b =
110001
110000
110001
110000
110000
```